# How to work with Unity and Text Mesh Pro or why are the canvas so huge?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

My first steps with a tuturial for Unity and the try to add an UI led me to Text Mesh Pro.

Adding it was quite easy but using it this way can't be intended?!
The Canvas object in the scene view is so huge and can not be adjusted.

To see the text I have to zoom out 100x

How do you work with it? Switching between UI view and game object alone is too cumbersome. Not to mention the non-existent overview of game-objects and UI Text.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The question really is leas why is canvas so large more why everything else small.

Comment: You do work with screen space canvas from the game view. 
You can hide it in the scene if you want

Comment: @BugFinder No, the question is what I can do against it, because I didn't make the size differences. Enlarging the playing field to 100 times did not help, because then everything (camera/light) is too small and no longer recognisable.  and I have not found a way to make the canvas smaller.

Comment: I didnt say make it bigger. Its supposed to be like that. If you use screen space it will always be massive compared to your scene. Unity even did a thing on it once. If you want it small make not screen space and it can then be a tiny tiny square in front of your camera

Comment: @BugFinder I know you didn't say that, but I'm also trying to find a solution myself. ;-)  
But thanks,. If I set the render mode to "world space", I can adjust the size of the canvas.

Comment: The screen space canvas is set to 1px equals 1 unit.  A screen width of 600px will result in a canvas that is 600 units wide.  [UI Canvas](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html) reference gives a quick overview of the different render modes.